# Storage on android 11

Tags: java, android, android-11

I want to store images, videos, audio, and all types of documents like (jpg, mp4, gif, txt, pdf, CSV and etc.) in one folder like 'ABC' and store all that in ("ABC") folder.

I have lots of R&D and done from ALL files access(MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) permission and working perfectly as I said as above but play store was rejected due to all file access permission.

Play Store Reject Message
Policy: "Access all files" permission

```
File and directory attributes on your device are considered your personal and sensitive information and are subject to your personal and sensitive information policies and the following requirements:

The access that your app requests should be limited to device storage, which is essential for your app to function. You cannot request access to device storage for third parties for purposes unrelated to essential app features for your users.
Android devices running Android R (Android 11) or later require MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission to manage access in shared storage. Any app that targets R or later and requests a wide range of access to shared storage (“access to all files”) must pass a proper access review before it can be published. Apps that are allowed to use this permission must clearly display a message to the user asking them to enable Access to all files in the Special App Access settings. For more information on this requirement for R, see this help article.

Find out more about the Access All Files permission
Find out Android storage use cases and recommended methods
Please resolve this issue in Google Play Console.
.
Problem: I need to use the Media Store API

The "Access All Files" permission has been requested, but only media files need access for important features of the app. The MediaStore API allows apps to access and interact with media on external storage volumes without the need for "access to all files."

Update your app to use the Media Store API and remove the "Access All Files" (MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) permission.
```

So please help me have anyone idea using Scoped Storage how it works like create a folder on storage like /data/ABC and store all documents as I mentioned like (jpg, mp4, gif, txt, pdf, CSV and etc.)

I want to like please check below steps

- Create a folder (not in a folder like pictures, video, audio, document and download as we have on File manager)
- Store file and images in "Created Folder"
- Store Download File in "Created Folder"
- Easily open after download
- Update and Delete Image

Please help me through the coding level if you used it because I have lot's of R&D but not get any document so please don't share any document so if you have used please help me because before 29 API levels it's working and on 29 API level I set `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` on manifest so I was also worked for me but android 11(30)  what we do please give me a proper solution.

Used code like below

> final String directoryFolder =
> Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + "ABC";
>
> ```
>     File file = new File(directoryFolder);
>     if (!file.exists()) {
>         file.mkdir();
>     }
> ```

getting error like below

> com.androidnetworking.error.ANError:
> com.androidnetworking.error.ANError: java.io.FileNotFoundException:
> /storage/emulated/0/ABC/19429202106171621.pdf: open failed: EPERM
> (Operation not permitted)

Comment: Create your ABC folder in public Documents folder.

Comment: Or otherwise store files in getExternalFilesDir("ABC").

Comment: Please give more code like the same to create a folder then store any document or a MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is set on manifest or not give me all the things. thanks

Comment: You can create folders and files in the usual way. And that has nothing to do with Android 11 as the code is the same as before 11. And you do not need MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.

Comment: Interesting. And now? This is a coding site. Not an error only site. Further: What does it have to do with your ABC folder or the paths i suggested?

Comment: I update my post please check and let me know what I update in my code

Comment: You should read my first comment. And the code you posted can never produce that error. So what are you up to? `if(!mkdir()) return;` You should have added that line before you try to create a file in a directory that does not exist. Repeat: `Further: What does it have to do with your ABC folder or the paths i suggested?`

Comment: Have to more thing like coding level so it very helps full for me like below 10 this code is working or not and so more for storage code.